# Strange Clang behavior. Simple snippet gives wrong result

Tags: c, scanf

This snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char cbuf[4], nl;
    int n;
    const char *s = "GET\n";

    if (sscanf(s, "%3[^\n]%1[\n]%n", cbuf, &nl, &n) < 2)
        return -1;

    printf("%s\n", cbuf);
    return 0;
}
```

gives wrong result. Nothing is printed in terminal. Debugger shows that resulting `cbuf` has following structure:

```
[0] = '\0'
[1] = 'E'
[2] = 'T'
```

When I paste this code in [online GDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com/) program gives expected result. It prints `GET`.

My question is, what is the reason for such behavior?

My clang version is 3.8.0

Comment: ... so there isn't a reason, apart from *undefined behaviour* and you might get what you expect, might not, etc.

Comment: There's a plausible manifestation of UB: What if `sscanf` writes the terminating `'\0'` into `(&nl)[1]` (which doesn't exist), which happens to be the same memory location as `cbuf[0]`?

Comment: @user3121023 Your suggetion helped. Thanks!

Comment: @melpomene I think that (&nl)[1] was indeed at cbuf[0]. Upvoted both comments.